symbolical and numerical nested integrals
I'm working on reproducing a calculation from this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03972 for my thesis but I'm struggling with how to properly implement the nested integrals in Python, specifically how to handle them symbolically and numerically.
I want to reproduce the left panel in Figure 1, which requires computing the energy densities rho_phi(T) (eq. 3.4) and rho_N(T) (eq. 3.7). Let's focus on rho_phi(T). First, I compute the distribution function f_phi(T,p) as in eq. 3.2.
From my understanding the the integral in lambda should be solved symbolically because the lower limit is T, and I want to have a function of T and p to later integrate numerically or symbolically over p to get rho_phi(T) and n_phi(T) (eq. 3.5)
The problem is given by the degrees of freedom g_*s(T), which I take from this file http://www.laine.itp.unibe.ch/eos15/.
If I keep g_*s(T) as a symbolic function in sympy, it does not solve the integral and returns an Integral object instead. If I instead plug in a numerical value for T, the integral gets solved (because g_*s(T) is tabulated). I then numerically integrate my f_phi over p to get rho_phi.
To generalize for all the temperatures I simply loop over all my values of T. However, since I do not obtain the same results of the paper I do not know if this approach is incorrect or of there are other mistakes.
Is there a smarter way to handle the symbolic integration involving the numerical values of g_∗s(T)?
Is there a more effective approach to integrate these functions both symbolically and numerically?
Any help will be very much appreciated as I am quite lost. Thank you!
Here is the code
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from sympy import symbols, pi, sqrt, integrate, Function, exp, lambdify, oo
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Reading data
data = np.loadtxt('temperatures_data_SM.dat', skiprows=1)
T_values = data[:, 0]
g_s = data[:, 7]

# necessary to compute dg_*s/dT in Delta_*s
e = data[:, 2]  # energy density / T^4
c = data[:, 4]  # heat capacity / T^3

# Interpolating functions for g_s, c, and e
g_s_func = interp1d(T_values, g_s, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')
c_func = interp1d(T_values, c, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')
e_func = interp1d(T_values, e, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')

# Define symbols for SymPy
T, lam, p = symbols('T lam p')

# Constants
m_phi = 10.0  # MeV
tau_phi = 20.0  # s 
T_cd = 5.0e3  # MeV
T_D_cd = 5.0e3  # MeV

Grav = 6.70881e-45 # hbar c^4 MeV^-2
hbar = 6.58211899e-22 # MeV s
G8P3 = sqrt(8*pi*Grav/3)/hbar

T_values = T_values[T_values<T_cd]

# Define symbolic functions for the interpolations
g_s_sym = Function('g_s_sym')(T)
c_sym = Function('c_sym')(T)
e_sym = Function('e_sym')(T)

# Define function to compute p_* 
def p_star_sym(lam, T, p):
    return p * (g_s_sym**(1/3) * lam / (g_s_sym**(1/3) * T))

# Define function to compute Delta_*s
def Delta_s_sym(lam, T):
    return lam / (3 * g_s_sym) * (30 / lam * c_sym - 120 / lam * e_sym)

# Define function to compute expansion rate
def Hubble_sym(lam, T):
    rho_SM = (pi**2 / 30) * g_s_sym * lam**4  
    return G8P3 * sqrt(rho_SM)

# Define the function to integrate symbolically
def integral_term_sym(lam, p, T):
    return (m_phi / sqrt(m_phi**2 + p_star_sym(lam, T, p)**2)) * (1 + Delta_s_sym(lam, T)) / (Hubble_sym(lam, T) * lam)

# Define function that substitutes numerical values after symbolic integration
def evaluate_expression(T_value, inner_int_res):
    g_s_sub = g_s_func(T_value)
    c_sub = c_func(T_value)
    e_sub = e_func(T_value)
    
    return inner_int_res.subs({
        g_s_sym: g_s_sub,
        c_sym: c_sub,
        e_sym: e_sub,
        T: T_value
    })

def tot_func(T_example):

    # Perform the symbolic integration in f_phi(p,T)
    int_res_1 = integrate(integral_term_sym(lam, p, T), (lam, T_example, T_cd))

    # Evaluate the integration result at T = T_example
    mid_res_1 = evaluate_expression(T_example, int_res_1)

    # Compute final f_phi(p, T_example)
    factor = exp(sqrt(m_phi**2 + p_star_sym(T_example, T_cd, p)**2) / T_D_cd) - 1 
    f_phi = exp(- mid_res_1 / tau_phi) / factor

    # Compute and return rho_phi
    rho_phi = p**2 * sqrt(p**2 + m_phi**2) * f_phi

    integrand_function = lambdify(p, rho_phi, 'numpy')

    integral_p_value, error = quad(integrand_function, 0, np.inf, epsabs= np.inf)

    return float(integral_p_value / (2 * pi**2))


lst = []
for i in tqdm(T_values[T_values<T_cd]):
    rhos = tot_func(i)
    lst.append(rhos)


You are asking too many questions in one here. Focus on one thing at a time and explain it here in the question (don't assume that others are going to follow the links or read a paper or anything).

@OscarBenjamin Thank you for your comment. I have tried to include here the relevant equations, but I figured that without the math mode they would be not very helpful. I have edited my question trying to simplify it, hope it is better now.

It's not clear what you're asking, but you don't need symbolics for a T-dependent integral. Define a Python function of a numerical integral, and use that for any given T. This might or might not be what you're already doing.
